# open, update and save spreadsheet c#

Tags: c#, excel, loops, sql-update

I have a bunch of excel spreadsheets, which have internal sql queries to get data from an SQL server.

I want to loop through those sheets, update them and then save them.
Is there a way to open, update, save and close a sheet in c# ?

cheers

Comment: Yes, there is. Google will help a lot!

Comment: Asked google, didn't help ...

Answer (score 0):

See the following from [How to automatically refresh excel formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200208/how-to-automatically-refresh-excel-formulas)

> In C#, use Application.Calculate() for evaluating all open workbooks,
>   Workbook.Calculate() in order to evaluate a workbook or
>   Worksheet.Calculate() for a worksheet.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.calculate.aspx

Basically just add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, them call `Worksbooks.Open` to open a workbook file.  You can then call `Calculate` or `CalculateFull`, then `Save` on the application object to write the latest changes back.

Comment: I did this :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j67l5to59933do2/excelError.PNG?dl=0

does not work. Changes in the DB are not applied :/

Comment: Strange  you could try CalculateFullRebuild instead to see if that helps?  Or you could show the application and see if the figures are changing but just not being saved correctly?  Otherwise can you confirm how your SQL queries are configured?

Comment: I used CalculateFullRebuild as well, didn't work :/
yes sql querys are used and working on manual update. And yes I can access the files correctly via C#, no exeptions